# Remove specific char from String

Tags: java, android, string, removeall

How To remove a specific Character from a String. I have a Arraylist testingarray.

```
String line=testingarray.get(index).toString();
```

I want to remove a specific character from line.

I have Array of uniCodes

```
int uniCode[]={1611,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618};
```

i want to remove those characters that have these Unicodes.

Comment: Can you give an example what you mean by _remove a specific character_

Comment: For Example I want to remove 'd' from a string( this is a dog ). Result should be( this is a og ).

Comment: Do you want to remove all `d` characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove special characters from an string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-an-string)

Comment: @Amulya Khare yes i want to remove all d characters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use :

```
NewString = OldString.replaceAll("char", "");
```

in your Example in comment use:

```
NewString = OldString.replaceAll("d", "");
```

for removing Arabic character please see following link

[how could i remove arabic punctuation form a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580287/how-could-i-remove-arabic-punctuation-form-a-string-in-java)

[removing characters of a specific unicode range from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013341/removing-characters-of-a-specific-unicode-range-from-a-string)

Comment: thanks . i did it but i did't get what i want. Basically i want i have 7 unicodes of Arabic characters , int uniCode[]={1611,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618}; i want to remove those words that have these unicodes

Comment: @ Shayan pourvatan thanks a lot . That is what i was searching i got my solution.

Answer (score 8):

you can replace character using replace method in string.

```
String line = "foo";
line = line.replace("f", "");
System.out.println(line);
```

output

```
oo
```

Comment: Cleanest solution for my application.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a single char, there is no need to use replaceAll, which uses a regular expression. Assuming "H is the character you want to replace":

```
String line=testingarray.get(index).toString();
String cleanLine = line.replace("H", "");
```

update (after edit):
since you already have an int array of unicodes you want to remove (i'm assuming the Integers are decimal value of the unicodes):

```
String line=testingarray.get(index).toString();
int uniCodes[] = {1611,1614,1615,1616,1617,1618};
StringBuilder regexPattern = new StringBuilder("[");
for (int uniCode : uniCodes) {
    regexPattern.append((char) uniCode);
}
regexPattern.append("]");
String result = line.replaceAll(regexPattern.toString(), "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("your_character","");
```

Example:

```
String line=testingarray.get(index).toString();
String result = line.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
```

Comment: replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","")    - this is working as a regEx and if anything is present in line , it is replacing with blank( trimming it).