# Remove any given character form any given string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

i was trying to make a function that can take a char and a string as arguments and remove that char from the string.

```
function removeCharacter(char, str) {
    return str.replace(char, '');
}
ex: removeCharacter('r', "character") - > chaacte
```

Doing this way only removes the first char so I found out about the global Regex, but here is where I hit a wall...how can I make it so it can take any given char something like:

```
str.replace(/char/g, '')
```

I want pass that char as an argument in the function and remove all of them. Is there a way to this with regex or should i use a for statement? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769908/remove-specific-char-from-string

Comment: your reference is in Java :)

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a Regexp.

```
function removeCharacter(char, str) {
    var reg = new RegExp(char, 'g');
    return str.replace(reg, '');
}
```

**[edit]**
This answer only works for characters which are not special characters from the RegExp point of view (like '/', '(', '.'). Otherwise it will fail or have unexpected behaviour. cf [@Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44871902/3410584).

Comment: That was what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @AlinFaur: I doubt it is what you need. Try with `(`.

Answer (score 2):

To remove multiple occurrences of a char, you [need to use a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) in JavaScript, a regex that is constructed with a `g` (global) modifier.

However, you can't just use `/char/g`, you need to declare the regex using a *constructor notation*, `new RegExp(char, "g")`.

And since some chars are reserved, special regex metacharacters, you must [escape them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

So, what you need is

```js
function removeCharacter(char, str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(char.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'), '');
}
console.log(removeCharacter("(", "(abc(")); // => abc
```