# Remove Arabic non-alpha-numeric characters from a string in Java

Tags: java, arabic

How can I remove all non-alpha-numeric Arabic characters from a string in Java?

Comment: Probably using a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Do you mean things like Arabic full stop, Arabic comma etc.? What about non-alpha-numeric characters which are not Arabic? What about Arabic characters which are alpha numeric?

Answer (score 1):

use regex `[^A-Za-z0-9 ]` the regex will only allow alphabets from A to Z and a to z also numericals from 0 to 9. nothing else

Comment: And the "Arabic" bit?

Comment: thanks ! it works... I just used "[^A-Za-zأ-ْ-9 ]" (to support both Arabic and English non-alpha-numeric

Comment: There is a problem with this pattern. It also removes Alif (أ) and Hamza (ء) from the arabic string which is wrong. How to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete answer:

```
   String patternString = "";
    Pattern pattern = null;
    Matcher matcher = null;
    String normalizedString = "";

    patternString = "[^A-Za-zأ-ْ-9 ]";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    normalizedString = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple solutions and nothing works prominently. I tried all the solution from the current thread as well as from here - [how could i remove arabic punctuation form a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580287/how-could-i-remove-arabic-punctuation-form-a-string-in-java/51415717).

As no other solution works completely, I have created method which will retain only arabic characters and rest all chars will be removed as below -

```
public static String findArabicString(String s) {
    StringBuilder finalValue = new StringBuilder();
    
     if (null != s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
            int c = s.codePointAt(i);
            if ((c >= 0x0600 && c <= 0x06E0))
                finalValue.append((char) c);
            i += Character.charCount(c);            
        }
     }
    
    System.out.println(finalValue.toString());
    return finalValue.toString();
}
```

The method can be customized as required, for example I want to retain space and arabic characters, then there is a slight chnage required in the testing condition as below -

```
public static String findArabicString(String s) {
    StringBuilder finalValue = new StringBuilder();
    
     if (null != s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
            int c = s.codePointAt(i);
            // 32 is unicode for white space
            if ((c >= 0x0600 && c <= 0x06E0) || c == 32)
                finalValue.append((char) c);
            i += Character.charCount(c);            
        }
     }
    
    System.out.println(finalValue.toString());
    return finalValue.toString();
}
```

I hope this will help to anyone facing similar issue as I do.

Answer (score 0):

To remove arabic alpha from a string you can use the method below :

```
 public void removeArabicChars() {
        String input = "This string contains Arabic characters هذا النص يحتوي على حروف عربية";
        String output = input.replaceAll("\\p{InArabic}", "");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```